# Change Variable only if other Variables have changed and Update is requested

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the following Problem:

```
struct Item {
    var foo: Int

    init(_ iFoo: Int = 0){
        self.foo = iFoo
    }
}

class TestObject {
    @Published var items = [Item(1), Item(2), Item(3), Item(4)]

    private var avg:Double = 0.0{
        didSet{
            print("didSet: avg: '\(self.avg)'")
        }
    }

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    private var isItemChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Item], Never>{
        self.$items
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init(){
        self.isItemChangedPublisher
            .map{ items in
                var sum = 0
                for item in items{
                    sum += item.foo
                }
                return Double(sum)/Double(items.count)}
            .assign(to: \.avg, on: self)
            .store(in: &cancellableSet)
    }

    func changeItem(at index: Int, to value: Int){
        if self.items.count < index{
            self.items.append(Item(value))
        }else{
            self.items[index].foo = value
        }
    }

    func getAvg() -> Double{
        //Request: Items changed --> Change Value of avg here
        //Set Value of avg only if items has changed AND "Request" is called
        //  - don't set the new Value if Items has not changed and "Request" is called
        //  - don't set the new Value if Items has changed, but "Request" is not called
        return self.avg
    }
}

var bar = TestObject()

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 20)
bar.changeItem(at: 0, to: 3)

print("1. avg: '\(bar.getAvg())'")

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 20)

print("2. avg: '\(bar.getAvg())'")

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 30)

print("3. avg: '\(bar.getAvg())'")

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 20)
```

The Value of `var avg` is set every Time I change the items-Array. I understand that this is the intended behavior.

But is there any way to update the Variable `avg` only if the items-Array has changed AND something like a "Request" is called. 
If only the items have been changed the Variable `avg` should not be update, also if only the "Request" is called, but no items have been changed, the Variable shouldn't be updated.

I don't have any clue how to do this.

Do you have any idea to do this with the combine framework or with another solution?

Edit - 23.Jan.2020:

I could do something like that:

```
import Combine

struct Item: Equatable {
    var foo: Int

    init(_ iFoo: Int = 0){
        self.foo = iFoo
    }
}

class TestObject {
    @Published var items = [Item(1), Item(2), Item(3), Item(4)]

    private var newAverage: Double? {
        didSet{
            print("didSet: items changed --> newAverage: '\(String(describing: self.newAverage))'")
        }
    }

    private var average:Double = 0.0{
        didSet{
            print("didSet: average: '\(self.average)'")
        }
    }

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    private var isItemChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Item], Never>{
        self.$items
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init(){
        cancellable = self.isItemChangedPublisher
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map{Double($0.map{$0.foo}.reduce(0, +))/Double($0.count)}
            .sink{self.newAverage = $0}
    }

    func changeItem(at index: Int, to value: Int){
        if self.items.count < index{
            self.items.append(Item(value))
        }else{
            self.items[index].foo = value
        }
    }

    func getAverage() -> Double{
        if self.newAverage != nil{
            self.average = self.newAverage!
            self.newAverage = nil
        }
        return self.average
    }
}

var bar = TestObject()

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 20)
bar.changeItem(at: 0, to: 20)
print("1. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 1, to: 20)
print("2. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 1, to: 20)
print("3. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 3, to: 20)

/*
 prints:
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'Optional(2.5)'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'Optional(6.75)'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'Optional(11.5)'
 didSet: average: '11.5'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'nil'
 1. avg: '11.5'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'Optional(16.0)'
 didSet: average: '16.0'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'nil'
 2. avg: '16.0'
 3. avg: '16.0'
 didSet: items changed --> newAverage: 'Optional(20.0)'
 */
```

But, I'm still looking for a solution with combine only (without the dirty solution with the `newAverage` variable).

I also tried a solution with a custom DispatchQueue (it is just an attempt, not a good solution or idea):

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct Item: Equatable {
    var foo: Int

    init(_ iFoo: Int = 0){
        self.foo = iFoo
    }
}

struct MyQueue {
//    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue", attributes: .concurrent, target: .global())
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "myQueue")

    init(){
        self.queue.suspend()
    }

    func releaseData(){
        self.queue.resume()
        self.queue.suspend()
    }
}

class TestObject {
    @Published var items = [Item(1), Item(2), Item(3), Item(4)]

    private var average:Double = 0.0{
        didSet{
            print("didSet: average: '\(self.average)'")
        }
    }

    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let myQueue = MyQueue()
    private var isItemChangedPublisher: AnyPublisher<[Item], Never>{
        self.$items
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    init(){
        cancellable = self.isItemChangedPublisher
            .removeDuplicates()
            .map{ items in
                Double(items.map{ $0.foo }.reduce(0, +))/Double(items.count)}
            .buffer(size: 1, prefetch: .keepFull, whenFull: .dropOldest) //The Buffer changes nothing
            .receive(on: self.myQueue.queue)
            .assign(to: \.average, on: self)
    }

    func changeItem(at index: Int, to value: Int){
        if self.items.count < index{
            self.items.append(Item(value))
        }else{
            self.items[index].foo = value
        }
    }

    func getAverage() -> Double{
        self.myQueue.releaseData()
        return self.average
    }
}
var bar = TestObject()

bar.changeItem(at: 2, to: 20)
bar.changeItem(at: 0, to: 20)
print("1. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 1, to: 20)
print("2. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 1, to: 20)
print("3. avg: '\(bar.getAverage())'")
bar.changeItem(at: 3, to: 20)

/*
 Prints:

 didSet: average: '2.5'
 1. avg: '2.5'
 didSet: average: '6.75'
 didSet: average: '11.5'
 2. avg: '11.5'
 didSet: average: '16.0'
 3. avg: '16.0'


 But im looking for:

 didSet: average: '11.5' (because 2.5 and 6.5 are dropped)
 1. avg: '11.5'
 didSet: average: '16.0'
 2. avg: '16.0'
 3. avg: '16.0'
 */
```

but that doesn't work either...

Comment: You can insert a .removeDuplicates before the .map in didItemsChanged publisher. That would avoid recalculation when items hasn’t changed (won’t necessarily be more efficient). And as for calling request, I don’t see it, but that’s a function? If it is, then just do everything then.  Because then the whole thing isn’t asynchronous anymore. No need for Combine.

Comment: The example code is very simplified to show the point and doesn't necessarily make sense. It´s only to show and get the point. "Request" is a placeholder to show where I would like to ask the Publisher/Subscriber for a new value, like a function call. I wonder if it is possible to call something like a function to set a new value for `avg`, but only if the items has changed. If I simply call a function, the variable gets a new value every time I call it

Comment: I see. Well `.removeDuplicates` may still help. In init() as the first operator on the publisher, like `self.isItemChangedPublisher.removeDuplicates()`. Add it then add a `.breakpoint` right after to see if is indeed recognizing duplicates and stopping the publisher from getting to the sink and redoing the calculation. You would have to make `Item` conform to Equatable though.

Comment: `.removeDuplicates` is a useful addition but I still have the problem, that I don't want to update the var `avg` "automatically". I want to update the variable only if something changed and I "request" the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the things simple!

```
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


enum Operator {
    case count
    case sum
    case average
}

class TestObject {
    @Published var items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    @Published var result: Double = .nan

    private var count: Double {
        Double(items.count)
    }

    private var average: Double {
        guard items.count > 0 else {
            return .nan
        }
        return sum / count
    }

    private var sum: Double {
        return Double(items.reduce(0, +))
    }


    func request( _ operation: Operator) {
        switch operation {
        case .count:
            result = count
        case .sum:
            result = sum
        case .average:
            result = average
        }
    }
}

let test = TestObject()

let pub = test.$result.sink { (res) in
    print("Result:", res)
}

test.items[0] = 10
test.items[1] = 20
test.items[2] = 30

test.request(.sum)
test.request(.average)
test.request(.count)

test.items.append(contentsOf: [1, 2, 3])

test.request(.average)
```

prints only initial value and on request ...

```
Result: nan
Result: 64.0
Result: 16.0
Result: 4.0
Result: 10.0
```

If you are in trouble to see initial value of result, you can adopt the code, but it will be harder to use with SwiftUI

```
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true


enum Operator {
    case count
    case sum
    case average
}

class TestObject {
    @Published var items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    //@Published var result: Double = .nan

    let result = PassthroughSubject<Double,Never>()

    private var count: Double {
        Double(items.count)
    }

    private var average: Double {
        guard items.count > 0 else {
            return .nan
        }
        return sum / count
    }

    private var sum: Double {
        return Double(items.reduce(0, +))
    }


    func request( _ operation: Operator) {
        switch operation {
        case .count:
            //result = count
            result.send(count)
        case .sum:
            //result = sum
            result.send(sum)
        case .average:
            //result = average
            result.send(average)
        }
    }
}

let test = TestObject()

/*
let pub = test.$result.sink { (res) in
    print("Result:", res)
}*/

let pub = test.result.sink { (res) in
    print("Result:", res)
}

test.items[0] = 10
test.items[1] = 20
test.items[2] = 30

test.request(.sum)
test.request(.average)
test.request(.count)

test.items.append(contentsOf: [1, 2, 3])

test.request(.average)
```

the result value will be publish only on request (no initial value is available)

```
Result: 64.0
Result: 16.0
Result: 4.0
Result: 10.0
```

UPDATE:

using `.removeDuplicates()` doesn't help to reduce the computation at all. It works as a  "filter" on the publisher.

what you would like to have is simple, you have to store result of every "operation" and publish it on separate "operation"

changed part

```
    private var _last: Double = .nan


    private var count: Double {
        Double(items.count)
    }

    private var average: Double {
        guard items.count > 0 else {
            return .nan
        }
        _last = sum / count
        return _last

    }

    private var sum: Double {
        _last = Double(items.reduce(0, +))
        return _last
    }


    func request( _ operation: Operator) {
        switch operation {
        case .count:
            //result = count
            result.send(count)
        case .sum:
            //result = sum
            result.send(sum)
        case .average:
            //result = average
            result.send(average)
        case .last:
            result.send(_last)
        }
    }
```

now you have one more "operation request"

```
test.request(.last)
```

it will only publish last result, without any computation

and don't forget tu update before try :-)

```
enum Operator {
    case count
    case sum
    case average
    case last
}
```

Comment: It's almost what I looked for. Just add `.removeDuplicates()` to the Publisher and it's perfect --> `let pub = test.$result.removeDuplicates().sink {}`, with the remove Duplicates I can call `test.request(.count)` twice in a row and the value is printed once only. Great!

Comment: @3xypn0s you could use but because the value is updated on demand, it is redundant at all. just don't ask the result, if you don't need it! any number of subcribers could subscribe, may be with different processing requirements, let them to consume the data, as they need it.

Comment: But what if I would like to use the result of a complex computation (imagine the calculation of the average would be really expensive, just for the example). So for that I store the result (in the example the average) in an extra variable, so that I can use it again and again without the expensive computation, but every time I’m using the result I would like to check if I have to calculate the results again, because the underlying values have changed. Because I don’t want to make the calculation again if I don’t need it I added the remove Duplicates. What’s your opinion on that?

Comment: i made an update with explanation, you can check easily in the playground, why .removeDuplicates() is not the best solution.